# What can I do with strange process during turn-off?

Tags: system-installation

Today I installed Ubuntu 18.04 as a side system to Windows 7, and every time I turn the system off, strange text with some kind of processes running. It's also frozen, so i can't do anything.

Can you please introduce me to this kind od problem? Is it usual? What can i do now? What can I do to prevent it?!

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the picture you posted is from system being shutdown? it looks like you took it when system was booting up.

Comment: It shows during the shut-down process. No reaction, no change, no text changing... Nothing. Just plain weird stuff.